# android shell has been granted superuser permissions

Tags: android, notifications

My Android mobile Samsung S4 suddenly started getting below notification repeatedly on screen 
com.system.dbprocess granted superuser permission for an interactive shell rooting

Any idea why we get this notification?
How can I hide these notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick google search it seems like its some kind of spyware. Unless you have previously rooted your phone, I highly suggest uninstalling it asap as the super user permissions give it access to your entire phone (it can install other viruses) and can be very dangerous.

Comment: Sorry to mention. I rooted my android phone. How to unroot in this case or stop notifications atleast?

Comment: If you rooted your phone, then there is an application that is installed that is using the super user app to grant itself super user permissions. If you wish to unroot your phone, the only option is to install the stock firmware. In either case, you should still see if the above mentioned app is indeed installed and uninstall it.

Comment: What is stock firmware and How can I bring my phone to normal stage or un root to see that there are no issues.

Comment: Stock firmware is the original OS with apps that the phone comes with directly from the manufacturer. You can download a copy of the stock firmware for your device here: [link](http://www.sammobile.com/)and follow the instructions here: (http://www.technobuffalo.com/videos/how-to-unroot-return-your-android-phone/)[link] to reset your phone. GL and be aware that this could potentially brick your phone if done incorrectly.